# ScrollView containing @State property causes glitchy scrolling - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

### This simple ScrollView has very glitchy scrolling every time `@State` property is updated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var currentTime: Double = 0
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("currentTime: \(currentTime)")
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { input in
            currentTime = input.timeIntervalSince1970
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

### Glitchy scrolling video. `ScrollView` not working.

[image]

### What I've tried

- Putting the `.onReceive` inside the `ScrollView`
- Updating the `@State currentTime` with other methods besides a timer. They all glitch like this.

### How can I get the `ScrollView` to smoothly scroll, even during `@State` updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bug! I was surprised how even is possible because i am updating my ScrollView all the time while scrolling! you need to add one line of code to solve the issue!

---

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var currentTime: Double = 0
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
            Color.clear.frame(height: 0)               // <<: Here!
            
            Text("currentTime: \(currentTime)")
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { input in
            currentTime = input.timeIntervalSince1970
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked in this specific case, but my actual (more complex) code was still broken. My `ScrollView` also had a `LazyVStack` with some children. I rearranged stuff and it worked. My advice is: if you see this issue, try to rearrange your nested views. Accepted this anyways cause it did fix the original question.

Comment: @joshuakcockrell: As your advice, you said: "try to rearrange", but in your original question there is literally just one content called `Text("currentTime: \(currentTime)")` How would you solve the original question with your advice? So as I said there is indeed a bug in ScrollView Xcode 12.4 (12D4e), I could solve the issue with completely unneeded `color`, and As I also mentioned in my answer, I was surprised with this issue, because it never happened to me, so my advice would be **code in moment!** that means what ever code helps and solves the issue with current version.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely can't fix the original question by rearranging stuff. Just saying if someone runs into this in the future, try out your answer of adding `Color.clear`, and if that doesn't work then try rearranging nested views.